# How to set Python 3.8 as my default python version on kali linux

Tags: python, linux, kali-linux

I installed python 3.8 in my kali linux OS, but when I type `python` in kali linux terminal it showing like this

```
> Python 2.7.18 (default, Apr 20 2020, 20:30:41)
```

How can I set Python 3.8 as my default?

Comment: Have you tried `python3` ? instead of `python`

Comment: System programs depend on the default python, so simply turning "python" into python 3.8 would make your system unrunnable. As mentioned, "python3" should work. I don't know kali linux, but it still uses python 2x?! Yikes.

Comment: Which version of Kali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this answers your question.
The easiest way would be to run  `alias python=python3` .
So, now if you run the command python it will load python3 instead of python while being under the same alias/command python.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is install non-default versions of programs under `/usr/local`. Then I configure the file `$HOME/.bash_profile` so that the `$PATH` variable has `/usr/local/bin` first, before `/usr/bin` and `/bin` (which might actually be the same physical directory on your system).

`$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# PATH starts with...
PATH="/usr/local/bin"

# add $HOME/bin if it exists...
if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ]; then
  PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/bin"
fi

# These should exist, add them as fall back....
PATH="${PATH}:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin"

# Some custom locations last
if [ -d /usr/local/arm-elf/bin ]; then
  PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/arm-elf/bin"
fi
if [ -d /opt/local/bin ]; then
  PATH="${PATH}:/opt/local/bin"
fi
```

This has the effect of making anything located in `/usr/local/bin` the default when I am using an interactive shell, and letting the system defaults remain in effect otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

first, check if you have python3.8 installed
use

ls /usr/bin/python*

then check for an alternative python version using

update-alternatives --list python

if the output of python3.8 is set to 2

To set the default python command to run python3.8

use this to create a persistent symlink

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2

the 2 depends on your python alternatives

then
python --version

Answer (score -1):

First remove python 2.7.18

Type >> *sudo apt purge -y python2-minimal*

install python latest version

Type >> *sudo apt install -y python3-pip*

latest version of python is installed!